# Visual Studio Code doesn't reopen files or folders

Tags: visual-studio-code

I usually open files in VSCode using command line. When I close it with many tabs and folders opened and try to launch it as `code blah`, it opens only the `blah` file, without restoring all of the previous opened ones.

Is there a way to force it restore everything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `code` to reopen the previous window

Running `code X` will open just file/folder `X`. This behavior is [by-design](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/37449) but we may add a flag to control it at some point